# add_submenu_page set for multiple roles

Tags: admin, admin-menu, add-submenu-page

I have this string:

```
add_submenu_page(basename(__file__), 'Events', 'Colloqui', 'subscriber', 'BW_events', 'BW_events');
```

How can I let this be available to editor(s) too? I tried ...

```
add_submenu_page(basename(__file__), 'Events', 'Colloqui', 'subscriber, editor', 'BW_events', 'BW_events');
```

... but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`add_submenu_page()` and similar functions accept a `capability`. Capabilities are slightly confusing in WordPress as every role name is a cap as well. So instead of just adding a role name, you could [just take a capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) that is shared between the roles of the Subscribers and the Editors.

As you can see from the [capabilities and roles table in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table), `read` for example is a capability that every role in WP has.